# Portable plain C function for extracting filename from path

Tags: c, filesystems, portability, ansi-c

I am looking for a portable way to extract the filename from a path string in ANSI C.

The paths are like the following ones:

```
C:\tmp\abc.txt

C:/tmp/abc.txt

c:/tmp\abc.txt

../abc.txt

c:tmp/abc.txt

c:abc.txt

abc.txt

./abc.txt

/home/user/abc.txt

/home/.././var/tmp/abc.txt
```

For each case I want to extract the "abc.txt"

Is there a general solution available? (I haven't found any here and with google)

Comment: Standard C doesn't have any built-in pathname parsing functions.

Comment: In short: No there's no "generic" solution since there's simply to many target platforms for C, all with their own directory separators (beyond the two slashes). Heck, I'll bet there's even some target platforms for C where there isn't even something like directories, or even files, not in the way we usually speak of them on a PC-like system.

Comment: On Unix, backslash and colon have no special meaning in pathnames, so they shouldn't be treated as filename delimiters.

Comment: Note: “ANSI C” is archaic. Are you really programming in decades-old ANSI C, or are you using a modern version of C?

Comment: You are right, maybe I should have used "Plain C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the C standard that specifies such a function or that requires implementations to provide one.

Furthermore, it is not possible to implement one yourself without tailoring it specifically to the target environment. Proof:

- On a Windows system, the file name portion of `abc\def.txt` is `def.txt`.
- On a macOS system, the file name portion of `abc\def.txt` is `abc\def.txt`.

Since the proper result for identical input is different on different systems, a function independent of the file name syntax for target environment cannot implement this.

Therefore, any such function must be written either for a specific implementation or implementations or must take into account and adapt itself for the environment it is compiled for.

I am not aware of any software that provides such a function, which is not to say none such exists.

Comment: This is what `#if defined(_WIN32) `and  `defined(__APPLE__) `are for...